# Importing appcompat-v7 into project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Hi guys I need to use appcompat-v7 in my project.
I have tried to copy /sdk/extra/.../.../libs/appcompat-v7-jar into myproject/libs but in my code there aren't any errors... 
When I run my app I can see this in debug:

```
// Compiled from ActionBarActivityDelegate.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
abstract class android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate {

// Field descriptor #63 Ljava/lang/String;
static final java.lang.String METADATA_UI_OPTIONS = "android.support.UI_OPTIONS";

// Field descriptor #63 Ljava/lang/String;
static final java.lang.String UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW = "splitActionBarWhenNarrow";

// Field descriptor #63 Ljava/lang/String;
private static final java.lang.String TAG = "ActionBarActivityDelegate";

// Field descriptor #69 Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity;
final android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity mActivity;

// Field descriptor #71 Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar;
private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar;

// Field descriptor #73 Landroid/view/MenuInflater;
private android.view.MenuInflater mMenuInflater;

// Field descriptor #75 Z
boolean mHasActionBar;

// Field descriptor #75 Z
boolean mOverlayActionBar;

// Field descriptor #75 Z
private boolean mEnableDefaultActionBarUp;

// Method descriptor #79      
(Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity;)Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegate;
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
static android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate  
createDelegate(android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity activity);
 0  getstatic android.os.Build$VERSION.SDK_INT : int [1]
 3  bipush 18
 5  if_icmplt 17
 8  new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateJBMR2 [2]
11  dup
12  aload_0 [activity]
13  invokespecial android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateJBMR2(android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity) [3]
16  areturn
17  getstatic android.os.Build$VERSION.SDK_INT : int [1]
20  bipush 16
```

http://imagebin.org/310148

Why??? any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`appcompat_v7` is an Android library project](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), not just a JAR. You need to follow [the instructions for adding the library project to your app](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

Comment: Yes, but ...
Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., <sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your application's project libs/

Comment: @roxdragon: That is the instruction for `android-support-v4.jar`. That is needed by `appcompat_v7`, but `appcompat_v7` itself is not just a JAR. Please follow [the instructions for "Adding libraries with resources"](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

Comment: @roxdragon: It looks like perhaps that file is not saved. Try saving it, as sometimes errors are not cleared until the file is saved.